# Узда и уздечка: есть ли разница?

Tags: значение-слов, однокоренные-слова

В продолжение темы о "браздах правления" у меня возник вопрос.
В свое время я занималась конным спортом, и по отношению к совокупности оголовья и повода все конники употребляли исключительно слово "уздечка", но никак не "узда". Еще уздечкой (и опять же никак не уздой) называется проволочный каркас на пробке шампанского. И еще несколько вещей (в челюстно-лицевой анатомии, например, а еще в окраске и т.д.). Но опять же, есть слово "узда", его чаще употребляют в литературе как в значении той же конской амуниции, так и в переносном смысле.
И вопрос такой: есть ли разница между понятиями "узда" и "уздечка"?

Answer (score 1):

Узда  родственна таким словам, как: узы, узел, уста, ус. Вообще-то это связь, связка, уздечка - малая связка. Уздцы - полный набор связок, одеваемых на голову, вместе с металлическими частями, в том числе и  во рту лошади. http://www.westernhorse.ru/images/amun/102.jpg
Уздечкой в медицине называют связку на половом органе мужчины.

Comment: Уздцы - у конников такого слова нет. Можно вести лошадь *в поводу* - иначе никак.  
А то, что в медицине Вы упомянули, называется семенной канатик. А уздечка находится во рту.))))

Comment: вы и там и там путаете, вам пример привели, учебной узды, оголовья, называемой уздечкой.  Под уздцы ведут, это крепко держат за место крепления повода к трензелю, а в поводу ведут, свободно держат повод не ограничивая движения лошади.
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D3%E7%E4%E5%F7%EA%E0

Answer (score 0):

Fuchoin Kazuki, Петро прав: уздечкой в медицине называют связку на половом органе мужчины.
Что касается основного вопроса:

> УЗДЕЧКА, -и; мн. род. -чек, дат. -чкам; ж.
> =Узда (1 зн.). Дёрнуть за уздечку. Надеть уздечку.
> УЗДА, -ы; мн. узды, узд; ж.
> 1.
> ***Удила с поводьями, надеваемые на голову лошади или других упряжных животных для управления ими.*** Надеть узду. Потянуть за узду. Лошадь не слушается узды.
> ***УЗДЦЫ, -цам; мн.
> Поводья около удил. Взять, держать под у. лошадь.***
> ***Оголовье - Уздечка со всем прибором для верховой лошади, а также часть уздечки - ремень, идущий за ушами вокруг головы до удил.***
>
> Как видите, в первом значении эти два слова совпадают. Уздечка -уменьшительно ласкательное от узда.